# Nesting Defaultdictionaries in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

I'm working on a piece of code and this is my first time implementing `defaultdict` from `collections`. 
Currently, I have a piece of code that works just fine as a `defaultdict`, but I'd really like to nest my dictionaries.

This is the code I have currently:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from re import findall

class Class: 
    def __init__(self, n, file):
        self.counts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
        self.__n = n
        self.__file = file

    def function(self, starting_text, charas):
        self.__starting_text = starting_text
        self.__charas = charas

        with open(self.__file) as file:
            text = file.read().lower().replace('\n', ' ')

        ngrams = [text[i : i + self.__n] for i in range(len(text))]

        out = self.counts
        for item in ngrams:
            data = []
            for word in findall( item+".", text):
                data.append(word[-1])
            self.counts = { item : data.count(item) for item in data }
            out[item] = self.counts
        self.counts = out
```

Some of the things in the code aren't yet implemented because I'm at a bit of a standstill, so please ignore anything that isn't applicable to this particular question!

If I run `print(self.counts)` at the end, my program runs something that looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<function Class.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f8c4a94bea0>, {'t': {'h': 1, ' ': 1, 'e': 1}, 'h': {'i': 1, 'o': 1}, 'i': {'s': 2}, 's': {' ': 2, 'h': 1, 'e': 1}, ' ': {'i': 1, 'a': 1, 's': 2}, 'a': {' ': 1}, 'o': {'r': 1}, 'r': {'t': 1}, 'e': {'n': 2, ' ': 1}, 'n': {'t': 1, 'c': 1}, 'c': {'e': 1}})
```

Which is great! But I'd really like to have those *inner* dictionaries be defaultdicts as well. In particular, if I run `self.counts['t']['h']`, I get `1`, as expected. 
However, a benefit of the defaultdict is having it give you `0` if a key is not available. Currently, if I run `self.counts['t']['x']` I get a keyerror, but I'd live to get `0` instead by having each inner list be a defaultdict as well.

I'm assuming this can be done somewhere in the chunk of code beginning with `out=self.counts`, but I'm a little unsure how I can achieve this.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example, which this isn't: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  In your constructor for Class - please think of a better name - you initialize self.counts to a default dictionary, each of whose values will also be a default dictionary.  That's what you said you wanted to do (the inner dictionaries are defaultdicts) and it seems to be already done at that point.  But then in function - please think of a better name - you assign some other objects to the same self.counts.  One of these assignments is actually inside a loop.  That's almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make data a `collections.Counter` or a `defaultdict` instead of a list (since you strictly don't care about the sequence of bits, only their occurrences count)
2. then `update` your `self.counts[item]` with the counter instead of assigning a dict
3. you could even do the update straight:

   ```py
   for item in ngrams:
       data = self.counts[item]
       for word in findall( item+".", text):
           data[word[-1]] += 1
   ```

   and that's about it, this will update the relevant counts straight into the defaultdict as originally defined

That aside much of the code is... not ideal, or odd

#### seems unnecessarily complex

You're getting each codepoint following your ngram, why not straight extract pseudo-ngrams of n+1 and split that up? Something along the lines of (untested, may be slightly off):

```py
for i in range(0, len(text)-n):
    ngram, follower = text[i:i+n], text[i+n]
    self.counts[ngram][follower] += 1
```

That also avoids the at-least quadratic complexity of your code (and the various constant complexities) which is a nice side-effect, though note that the original would implicitly skip followers of `\n` (a newline / line break) as wihout `re.DOTALL`, `.` "matches any character except a newline". So if you want to keep that behaviour you'll have to specifically test for and skip on `follower == '\n'`.

#### Reusing member variables as locals?

You're reusing `self.counts` as a local variable for some weird reason, saving it to `out`, setting it to weird stuff then re-loading it after having set it on itself, why isn't `out` the *inner* variable?

```py
        for item in ngrams:
            data = []
            for word in findall( item+".", text):
                data.append(word[-1])
            out = { item : data.count(item) for item in data }
            self.counts[item] = out
```

Not that that's very useful (possibly aside from printf-debugging utility), you can assign to `self.counts[item]` straight.

I also have no idea whatsoever what utility `__starting_text` and `__charas` have

#### double underscore prefixes

Don't. It doesn't matter what you're using them for, I'm reasonably sure you're wrong (because I've rarely encountered people who knew what these are for) and you should stop it.

If you want to hint to callers that something is an internal detail of the object, use a single underscore prefix. Though you probably don't need to do that either.

#### always pass an encoding to text-mode `open`

Seriously. `open(path)` works in text mode (automatically decodes the raw on-disk data to `str`), but the encoding it picks is whatever `getdefaultencoding()` returns which is as likely as not to be garbage. You don't want to use it to read the user's file, and you *really absolutely never* want to use it to read your own file. Explicitly provide `encoding='utf-8'`, it will avoid lots of grief down the line. If you need to infer encoding *maybe* use chardet.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this two lines:

```
self.counts = { item : data.count(item) for item in data }
out[item] = self.counts
```

You don't need the `out` variable. the problem is that you are creating a "normal" dict and assign it to `self.count`. Just use:

```
self.counts[item].update({ item : data.count(item) for item in data })
```

Comment: You probably don't even need to reify the items as a dict and could use a generator of tuples, though I guess the overhead of `count` would dwarf that minor efficiency anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not using any of the features of the `defaultdict`. It would work identically if you used a normal `dict` instead. It's also very confusing, as you're using several variable names (like `item` and `self.__counts`) for different things in different parts of the code.

But you can pretty trivially change it to use the `defaultdict` instead of doing things the hard way. Here's how I'd fix it:

```
def function(self, starting_text, charas):
    self.__starting_text = starting_text
    self.__charas = charas

    with open(self.__file) as file:
        text = file.read().lower().replace('\n', ' ')

    ngrams = set(text[i : i + self.__n] for i in range(len(text)))

    for item in ngrams:
        for word in findall( item+".", text):
            self.counts[item][word[-1]] += 1
```

This isn't exactly the same as your previous code, as it's not idempotent (if you call it repeatedly, you'll keep adding on to the counts, rather than replacing old counts with new ones). You probably can restore most of the old behavior by putting all the characters into a list (like your `data`) first, then setting the value in `self.__counts` only at the end. But then I'd probably prefer using a `collections.Counter` instead of doing it by hand (and I'd probably build the `Counter` in the loop, rather than having `defaultdict` do it for me).

On an unrelated note: Your code is using double leading underscores on several of your attributes. That's not generally encouraged for Python code. It enables name mangling, which transforms names like `self.__n` into `self._Class__n` (if `Class` is the name of the class the code using `__n` is written in, regardless of what type `self` is). It should not usually be used to mark something as "private", rather it's intended to avoid accidental name collisions when you can't know in advance what other names might be put into the same object namespace. For instance, a proxy or a mixin class might need to allow users to access any kind of attribute name, and the designer of the class can't know what those will be (and the designer of the objects that will be proxied or the classes that will be mixed with may not know of the proxy/mixin class's existence). If you just want to mark your attributes as "private", use a single leading underscore rather than two. Data privacy isn't enforced in Python, and trying to use name mangling for it is only misleading you (outside code that wants to access your attributes will still be able to do so). And name mangling makes debugging harder. The Python philosophy is that its programmers are all "consenting adults" and so they should be trusted to know not to misbehave with other code's internals (or to deal with the consequences if they do).